# Applications of the Riemann-Roch theorem to number theory

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Does anyone know if there are many applications of the Riemann-Roch theorem to number theory? I know it can be used to prove associativity of the group structure on elliptic curves but can it be used for anything more directly related to number theory? Or alternatively, could it be extended to hyperelliptic curves?

Comment: What do you mean, "extended to hyperelliptic curves"? Riemann-Roch (as typically stated in the context of curves) is for all curves.

Comment: Can the Riemann-Roch theorem be used to prove associativity of the group structure on hyperelliptic curves?

Comment: The only smooth curves that have a group structure are elliptic curves - the tangent bundle has to be trivial by the group action, so the genus must be 1.

Comment: In a different vein, Riemann-Roch is also related to Tate's thesis; for example, Tate literally calls the adelic Poisson summation formula the number theoretic Riemann-Roch, if I remember correctly. And with enough setup, it turns out that RR for curves over finite fields is equivalent to hitting a simple indicator function with the adelic Poisson summation.

Answer (score 1):

The sixth chapter of Andre Weil's *Basic Number Theory* and the third chapter of Jürgen Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory* are about the RR theorem in number theory.

Comment: Please use [markdown formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format text in your post, not MathJax. I've made the change for you this time.